# How to automatically load array from JSON using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have been playing around with building an ASP.Net MVC4 Application with knockoutjs.  I have a text box and a submit button; when the button is pressed whatever is in the textbox is sent to a database via json.  I would like to use knockoutjs to immediately update whatever is in the database to the browser, but I have been unable to accomplish this.

Currently the app writes data from the browser to the db correctly and I am able to display it by adding a button that calls the All() function.

JS:

```
function todo(id, isComplete, task) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = id;
    self.IsComplete = isComplete;
    self.Task = task,         

    self.Attach = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Todos/",
            type: 'post',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });
    }
}

function todoVM() {
    var self = this;
    self.todos = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.All = function () {
        self.todos.removeAll();
        $.getJSON("/api/Todos/", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                self.todos.push(new todo(val.Id, val.IsComplete, val.Task));
            });
        });
    };
    return self;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new todoVM(), document.getElementById('display'));
    ko.applyBindings(new todo(), document.getElementById('add'));
});
```

Partial View 1:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: todos">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsComplete" />
    <input class="todoItemInput" type="text" data-bind="value: Task, disable: IsComplete, blurOnEnter: true" />                        
</div>
<!--<input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Todos" data-bind="click: All" />-->
```

Partial View 2;

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Task" />
<input type="button"  value="Add" data-bind="click: Attach" />
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? Show us the code you tried for the success handler. In addition, what would help us help you: create a fiddle that mocks out the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Sorry, I am knew to knockoutjs (and my experience with Javascript is limited), I am not sure what a success handler or a fiddle is.  As I explained above, I would like to load the input from the textbox imediately after the 'Add' button is pressed.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: The success handler is in your code example. It is the function that gets called when the AJAX call returns successfully. With a fiddle I meant something like a [jsfiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/8yDbB/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sample below, when user click **Add** button the new task will add to database via ajax call, after it successfully added into database the callback function **success** will work. In **success** method, we add new task ( in this case result object return from server side ) into the **todos** observable. So you don't need to call **All** method.

> JavaScript

```
function todo(id, isComplete, task) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = id;
    self.IsComplete = isComplete;
    self.Task = task,         
}

function todoVM() {
    var self = this;
    self.todos = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTask=ko.observable();
    self.All = function () {
        self.todos.removeAll();
        $.getJSON("/api/Todos/", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                self.todos.push(new todo(val.Id, val.IsComplete, val.Task));
            });
        });
    };
    self.Attach = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Todos/",
            type: 'post',
            data: ko.toJSON(self.newTask()),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                self.todos.push(new todo(result.Id,
                                         result.IsComplete,
                                         result.Task)); 

        });
    };
    return self;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new todoVM(), document.getElementById('display'));
});
```

> HTML

```
<div id='display'>
    <div data-bind="foreach: todos">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsComplete" />
        <input class="todoItemInput" type="text" data-bind="value: Task,
           disable: IsComplete, blurOnEnter: true" />                        
    </div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: newTask" />
    <input type="button"  value="Add" data-bind="click: Attach" />
</div>
```

[For Reference](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/knockout/8L0T010413-Web-API-CRUD-Operations-with-Knockout.html)